# HTML Help in Delphi using EC Software Help Suite (EHS)

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-2010

I am using EC Software Help Suite (EHS) with Delphi 2010 and I am trying to show a HTML Help Fil e(*.chm) using the HelpROuter component

```
procedure TfrmMain.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 //load CHM file here
 HelpRouter1.Helpfile:= ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'VPUCDS.chm';
 HelpRouter1.HelpContent;
end;
```

It doe not display the help file. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't use EHS, but in my MainForm.FormCreate, I have:

```
Application.HelpFile := extractfilepath(Application.Exename) + 'behold.chm';
```

Then to bring up the Contents, I use:

```
Application.HelpShowTableOfContents;
```

That works for me.

Comment: @Shane, you should carefully read the Note section on the download page, http://www.ec-software.com/downloads_delphi.html. For Delphi 2005 and above, you can safely switch to the native functions.